# How to integrate $x\sin(1+2x)$

Tags: integration

Can someone be kind enough to show me the steps to integrate this, I'm sure it's by parts but how do I split up the sin part?
$$x\sin(1+2x)$$

Comment: I would try this: let $u=x$ and $v'=\sin(1+2x)$, then integrate by parts ($\int{uv'dx}=uv-\int{u'vdx}$).

Comment: @Helpthanks If you found an answer helpful then you should upvote it, so that others can see that you found it helpful. You can also "[accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)" an answer if you feel that it answers your question sufficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=x$ and $dv =\sin (1+2x) \, dx$
Then $v=-\frac{1}{2}\cos(1+2x)$. Now perform integration by parts.

Comment: Is it proper to evaluate this in radians or degrees for a double integral?

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=x$ and $v'=\sin(1+2x)$, then $u'=2$, $v=-\frac{\cos(1+2x)}{2}$:
\begin{align}\int{uv'\ dx}&=uv-\int{u'v\ dx}\\
\int{x\sin(1+2x)\ dx}&=-\frac{x\cos(1+2x)}{2}-\int{-\frac{2\cos(1+2x)}{2}\ dx}+C\\
&=-\frac{x\cos(1+2x)}{2}+\frac{\sin(1+2x)}{4}+C\\
\therefore\int{x\sin(1+2x)\ dx}&=\frac{1}{4}\sin(1+2x)-\frac{1}{2}x\cos(1+2x)+C
\end{align}

Comment: Should I evaluate finally in degrees or radians?

Comment: If unsure, I would always use radians.

Comment: I'm evaluating a double integral in normal co-ordinates does this make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an integration by substitution first. So, let $z=1+2x$ and note that this implies $x=\frac{z-1}{2}$, so we obtain the following. $$\frac14\int(z-1)\sin z\operatorname{d}z=\frac14\int z\sin\operatorname{d}z-\frac14\int \sin z\operatorname{d}z$$
Then, integrating $\sin z$ is standard, while $z\sin z$ is a standard easy example of integration by parts (and is probably in your notes!).

Comment: If I'm evaluating a double integral in Cartesians, would I evaluate the trig in degrees or radians?

Comment: Theoretically, there is no difference. However, certain formulae may require an input in radians. So it depends on what you are going to do with your answer.